# SQL function to list a column across tables without primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table listing states and one with cities, with State_number acting as a foreign key in the cities table. Is it possible to list the cities via their state name?

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
SELECT State_name, City_name 
FROM States, Cities 
JOIN Cities on States.State_number = Cities.State_number
WHERE States.State_name IN ('Munich', 'Brandenburg');
```

An example of the current output:

```
State_name
City_name
Bavaria
Munich

Bavaria 
Nuremburg

Brandenburg
Berlin
```

Whereas I am hoping for something like:

```
Munich
7
Brandenburg
10
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Aren't Munich and Brandenburg *cities*, not *states*?  What are the "7" and "10"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join them and apply a WHERE clause:

```
select st.state_name, c.city_name
from states s
  join cities c on s.state_number = c.state_number
where s.state_name = 'Bavaria';
```

To get the count of cities per state (which wasn't part of the original question), you can use a `group by`

```
select st.state_name, count(*) as number_of_cities
from states s
  join cities c on s.state_number = c.state_number
where s.state_name in ('Brandenburg','Bavaria')
group by st.state_name;
```

Comment: Currently thats listing each state and city separately. Is it possible to group them all within one heading for respective states, and have a count for the number of cities per state? At the moment I'm getting:
Bavaria
Munich

Bavaria
Nuremburg

Comment: Edit your question and show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: @Crocs123: that is a completely different question now.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want:

```
SELECT s.State_name, c.City_name 
FROM States s JOIN
     Cities c
     ON s.State_number = c.State_number
WHERE c.City_name IN ('Munich', 'Brandenburg');
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases!  And qualify all column references!
- Your filter should be on the city name not the state name.  I think that is the fundamental issue with your version of the query.